# Expand the containing view with it's content(label)

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uiview

I have a view with another wrapper view that holds a label and an imageView, like -

[image]

So, the view hierarchy is following -

```
UIView (parent view) -> 
                       UIView(container view) ->
                                                UILabel
                                                UIImageView
```

I want the container view to expand or shrink with label's content. So, if the label needs space to fit all the letters (max ~30 characters), the containerView should expand and so does the actual parent view. However, if there is only 10-15 characters, the container view should shrink. Basically allowing the label only the space needed to fit its content.

Can anyone suggests a good way to achieve this. Actual code is not required. Ideas will be sufficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you using Stevia layout ? i have a simple trick for this

Answer (score 0):

We can get it done with constraints.

Add yourContainerView constraints as leading, top, bottom and trailing to yourParentView(Trailing >= 10 ). Next add a Stack View on yourLabel+imageView and distribute both as fill and add constraints (Leading, Trailing, top and bottom) to yourContainerView.